# cross thread rtf format

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I use this function for updating a RichTextBox in cross thread situations

```
public void AddRtf(string text)
{
    // cross thread allowed
    if (rtb.InvokeRequired)
    {

        rtb.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
        {
            AddRtf(text);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        rtb.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is in \b bold\b0.}"; // this works
        rtb.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This "+text+"is in \b bold\b0.}"; // this not

    }

}
```

However, is not working, I can't see the RTF format when passing the "text" argument.

What will be the problem?

In fact, I need a simple solution to update a RichTextBox with COLOR, BOLD, UNDERLINE and some URLs inside a text. I wrote some functions for that such as rtb.AddLink() .AddBold() and so on, including a nice extension for adding URLs but seems more logical to pass RTF format and let the control to update formatting. But this will enforce me to break the text in each point where I need something in BOLD or whatever.

I think that HTML will be more convenient but I need a simple parser, at least simpler than HTMLAgilitypack.

So simple write in one line:

```
log.write("<font color="red">This is error</font> and this is the link... etc")
```

Anyone has a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` in the second part of the string:

```
@"{\rtf1\ansi This "+text+"is in \\b bold\\b0.}"
                                 ^^      ^^
```

or use an `@` again

```
@"{\rtf1\ansi This "+text+@"is in \b bold\b0.}"
                          ^
```

Comment: oopss :) Thank you, the @ in 2'nd part will be ok.